# Stateful streaming operation with Trigger.AvailableNow

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

As I understand, when running the streaming job in streaming mode the state is maintained during the window + watermark and then written when it can no longer be modified. How does this translate over to when we are using Trigger.AvailableNow? Does it just look at all the incoming events to get the new max timestamp and then only process events that are older than `max_event_time - window_time - watermark`?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I am wondering the same and don't see anything clear in documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never found this detail. Trigger.AvailableNow is older now, so maybe there are more docs about it online, but we ended up not using it, so I never explored this further.